# Concatenate json fields and search on concatenated value in MarkLogic

Tags: javascript, json, search, marklogic

I have below json format for storing person's firstname and lastname. I also store person's nickname as well.

```
{
  "Person": {
    "Records": [
      {
        "nameType": "Primary",
        "firstName": "Sagar",
        "lastName": "Dravid"
      },
      {
        "nameType": "konw as",
        "firstName": "Bunny",
        "lastName": "Bhau"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am developing typeahead search API for that I need to combine both first name and last name.
I am able to search on single individual field like only on either first name or on last name.
tried below code

```js
.where(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("firstName", [str + "* *"], ["wildcarded", "punctuation-insensitive", "diacritic-insensitive", "unstemmed", "case-insensitive"]))
  .map(mapper)
  .withOptions({
    search: ['filtered']
  })
  .result();
```

How I can concatenate json fields to achieve complete name search
so, if user types "Sagar Dravid" or "Bunny Bhau"  I should get result, but I should not get result if user types "Sagar Bhau" or "Bunny Dravid".
Any suggestions?

Comment: _"Is it possible"_ - try it first and see. Then if you have issues come back with a [mcve] and show that?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have edited question with code I tried.

Comment: If you can modify the document, adding a `fullName` attribute might be the easiest solution. Or if you use xquery, the `cts:search` `searchable expression` feature is helpful. I don't know how to accomplish it in javascript though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you could use a `cts.nearQuery` with a `cts.orQuery` for each property (lastName and firstName) that has a `cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery` for each of the name values (splitting the on space):

```
const searchString = "Bunny Bhau"
const query = 
  cts.nearQuery(
    searchString.split(" ").map(term => 
      cts.orQuery(["firstName", "lastName"]
        .map(property => 
          cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery(property, term + "*" , 
            ["wildcarded", "punctuation-insensitive", "diacritic-insensitive", "unstemmed", "case-insensitive"])
        )
      )
    ), 
    1)
```

Which would generate the following:

```
cts.nearQuery([
  cts.orQuery([
    cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("firstName", "Bunny*",
        [ "case-insensitive", "diacritic-insensitive", "punctuation-insensitive", "unstemmed", "wildcarded", "lang=en"], 1), 
    cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("lastName", "Bunny*",
        [ "case-insensitive", "diacritic-insensitive", "punctuation-insensitive", "unstemmed", "wildcarded", "lang=en"], 1)
  ],[]), 
  cts.orQuery([
    cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("firstName", "Dravid*",
        [ "case-insensitive", "diacritic-insensitive", "punctuation-insensitive", "unstemmed", "wildcarded", "lang=en"], 1), 
    cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("lastName", "Dravid*",
        [ "case-insensitive", "diacritic-insensitive", "punctuation-insensitive", "unstemmed", "wildcarded", "lang=en"], 1)
  ],[])],
  1,[], 1)
```

Comment: Would this give false positive if user searches for "Bunny Dravid"?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Looking for firstName OR lastName = "Bunny" AND firstName OR lastName = "Dravid" shouldn't match a doc unless it has Bunny AND Dravid in either of those fields.

Comment: (assuming that the JSON docs are being persisted separately for each of those Records in the example array)

Comment: I think it is a single document, the person's primary name is Sagar Dravid and alias is Bunny Bhau.

Comment: yes, now I see. Totally misunderstood. So, yes, the current solution would match across Records and return false positives. Need to see if that can be refined.